# What is the smallest number of 3-element subsets of a set of n elements where any element must be included with every other element at least one time?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

We have a set of *n* elements, and we need to find the lowest number of subsets with 3 elements where every element must be included with every other element, in at least one subset.

For example, if our set was {1,2,3,4}, our subsets would be {1,2,3} {2,3,4} {1,2,4} and the number would be 3. Can we generalise this for a set consisting of *n* elements? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe later ... gotta run!

Comment: I think the answer is $n-1\choose n-3$. I verified it for $n=3,4,5$. Try it for $n=6,7$.

Comment: ${n-1 \choose n-3} = {n-1 \choose 2}$ is an upper bound. But for example for $n=7$, there exists a famous example using only 7 sets (while this formula gives 15): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane Generally, $\frac{n \choose 2}3$ is a lower bound, which can be attained in some cases (like this)

Comment: We can generalize the Fano plane to get an example that attains the lower bound $\binom{n}{2}/3$ when $n = 2^k - 1$ for each $k \geq 3$. In particular, let our set be $S = \mathbb{F}_2^k \setminus \{0\}$, and let our subsets of 3 elements be the dimension 2 subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ without the origin (i.e. the sets of the form $\{x, y, z\}$ for distinct nonzero $x, y, z$ with $x+y+z = 0$). There are $\binom{|S|}{2}/3$ such sets, and $\{x, y, x+y\}$ is such a set for any distinct $x, y \in S$.